# question_on_approve() missing 1 required positional argument: 'created'

Tags: django, signals

I am trying to add points once the question is posted on the models. But it is showing question_on_approve() missing 1 required positional argument: 'created'.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=question)
def question_on_approve(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        oldQuestionObj = question.object.get(pk=instance.pk)
        questionObj = instance
        if oldQuestionObj.status != 1 and questionObj.status == 1:
            Points.objects.create(point=somepointfromPointsTableForQuestionAsked)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`created` is only avaliable with a `post_save`, since at that moment it is unknown if the object is a new record or an existing one. In case the object is not created yet, this normally means the `instance.pk` is not set yet, so you can work with:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=question)
def question_on_approve(sender, instance, **kwargs):
#                            no created ↑
    if instance.pk is not None:
        oldQuestionObj = question.object.get(pk=instance.pk)
        questionObj = instance
        if oldQuestionObj.status != 1 and questionObj.status == 1:
            Points.objects.create(point=somepointfromPointsTableForQuestionAsked)
```

Comment: @BhShr: dit you remove the `created` parameter?

Comment: `@receiver(pre_save, sender=question)
def question_on_approve(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.pk is not None:
        oldQuestionObj = question.object.get(pk=instance.pk)
        questionObj = instance
        if oldQuestionObj.status != 1 and questionObj.status == 1:
            Points.objects.create(point=15)`

Comment: @BhShr: can you please *edit* the question with the *full* traceback together with what you implemented, why is `somepointfromPointsTableForQuestionAsked` replaced by 15?

Comment: I had to modify another function as well. It works now. Thanks!